# Error when extract data from JSON string in Python (using Redshift)

Tags: python, json, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract data from a JSON string using SQL in Python. I get an error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Given below is the sample query that I am trying

```
dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""SELECT a.id, a.name,B.setup as setup,
         CASE WHEN (setup::JSON -> 'refcol')::TEXT = '{}' THEN 'data_missing'
         ELSE 'data_correct' END AS ColumnMapping
         FROM sales a join details b on a.sale_id = b.id 
        and a.name = {}""").format(sql.Literal(name)))
```

The above query runs fine if I exclude the last expression that extract data from JSON. The error throws up only when I include this JSON extraction column (col name : ColumnMapping ). Could anyone guide on how to fix this.

I am using Redshift DB. Thanks

Comment: There are two pairs of curly brackets but only one `format()` argument.

Comment: @KlausD., thanks for the reply. the first curly brackets checks for nulls. How could we handle such a case.

Comment: Add `'{}'` as the first argument to `format()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to format only the latter occurrence of `{}`, escape the first one with `'{{}}'`.

```
dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL("""SELECT a.id, a.name,B.setup as setup,
     CASE WHEN (setup::JSON -> 'refcol')::TEXT = '{{}}' THEN 'data_missing'
     ELSE 'data_correct' END AS ColumnMapping
     FROM sales a join details b on a.sale_id = b.id 
    and a.name = {}""").format(sql.Literal(name)))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The issue here is the first {} is to check for nulls. How could I cater in such as case.